# Did the Soviet Union build any commercial jetliners?

Tags: airliner, jet

I read about a [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tupolev_Tu-114) regarding the Soviet Union's Tupolev 114 which was comparable to the time's jetliners, and brought up the question: Did the Soviet Union build any jetliners for commercial use (i.e, airlines, firefighting).

Comment: I am seriously curious what kind thought process and presumptions could lead to such a question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

And who can forget the [TU-144](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tupolev_Tu-144), the world's first and biggest commercial supersonic transport aircraft.

Comment: industrial espionage on the concorde..and of a much lower quality!

Answer (score 10):

Of course. Probably more than any other single country except the US.

Tupolev [Tu-104](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tupolev_Tu-104), one of the first jetliners. For a short time, when the [Comet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Havilland_Comet) was grounded, it was the only jet airliner flying in the world.

[Tu-124](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tupolev_Tu-124), its development, the world's first jetliner with turbofan engines.

[Tu-134](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tupolev_Tu-134), further development; claimed to be the world's most produced twin jet of this class (80-pax).

[Tu-154](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tupolev_Tu-154), a trijet, USSR's most popular airliner. (Similar to B727 or Trident).

[Tu-204](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tupolev_Tu-204) was developed in the 1980s and is essentially 'Soviet', but never saw service in the USSR.

[Tu-144](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tupolev_Tu-144), of course. Although it first flew a few months before Concorde, it had extremely limited commercial (or better say, 'civil') service.

[Ilyushin Il-62](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ilyushin_Il-62), a long-range jet, a relatively rare example of a quad-jet with all engines on the back (similar to Vickers VC10).

[Il-86](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ilyushin_Il-86), USSR's first commercial widebody, and its later development [Il-96](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ilyushin_Il-96).

[Yakovlev Yak-40](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yakovlev_Yak-40), a small (30-40 pax) regional trijet, the world's first in its class.

[Yak-42](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yakovlev_Yak-42), the first Soviet jet with high-bypass turbofan; a trijet smaller than Tu-154.

All these jets (except Tu-144 and 204) were in wide use in the USSR, and most were exported at least to the Eastern Bloc countries and beyond. Of them, only Il-96 and Yak-42 remain in limited commercial use, although more are operated by air forces and government bodies.

Comment: The question was specifically about **jet**liners. 90s are not 'Soviet Union'. The only borderline case is Tu-204, which was developed during Soviet times, but never saw service in the USSR. I did miss Tu-144 though.